# java for loop sum and average of range

Tags: java

I have calculated the sum of a for loop range, however i do not know how to count and do the average for my solution. 
It must be done without any ifs. Just the For loop:

```
//defining the variables
        // Constants & Variables here
int i;
int numStart;
int numEnd;
double sum = 0;
double average=0;
double loopCount=0;
System.out.print("Enter Start number: "); // keep print line open
numStart = console.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter End number: ");
numEnd = console.nextInt();

        //enter thevalue
        for (i = numStart; i <= numEnd; i++ )
        {
            sum = sum + i;
            loopCount = numEnd - numStart;
            average = sum+1 / i;


        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println( "Sum is: " + sum);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println( "Average is: " + average);
        System.out.println();
```

Comment: you divide your sum by numEnd for average

Comment: that was what i tried first, however it is not just as that...look here what i get.
enter first number: 11
enter End number: 15

Sum is 65 (it will add 11+12+13+14+15)
but the Average using this formula of 

average = sum / numEnd;
it gives a wrong average of 4.33 instead of 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for (i = numStart; i <= numEnd; i++ )
    {
        sum = sum + i;
        loopcount++;
    }
    average = sum / loopcount;
```

Answer (score 3):

Why even use a `for`-loop. Thanks to Gauss we know the sum of all elements in range `[1 , n]` is `n * (n + 1) / 2`. The number of integers in the range is simply `numEnd - numStart + 1` and the average is the sum of all integers in range divided by the number of integers in the range.

So an optimized solution would look like this:

```
...
//got numStart and numEnd
int sum = numEnd * (numEnd + 1) / 2 - (numStart - 1) * numStart / 2;
int count = numEnd - numStart + 1;
average = sum / count;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
for (i = numStart; i <= numEnd; i++ )
                    {
                        sum = sum + i;
                        loopCount = numEnd - numStart;
                        average = sum /(loopCount+1);


                    }
```

or

```
for (i = numStart; i <= numEnd; i++ )
                {
                    sum = sum + i;
                    loopcount++;
                }
                average = sum / loopcount;
```